# How can I set dynamic height for TableView header heightForHeaderInSection?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UIView` with inside a `UITableView` and another `UIView`. Inside the `UITableView`, I have a header that contains a `UISearchController`, the search controller contains a `UISearchBar` . The problem is that when I start focusing on the search bar and editing the textField  (so when `searchController.searchBar.isFirstResponder()` ), the scope buttons come out, covering and hiding part of my first row of the table view.

That's why I'm trying to make the headerView height dynamic, so that I can change it whenever the search bar is the first responder. I tried the following but it won't work :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if searchController.searchBar.isFirstResponder() {
            return 40.0
        }
        else{
            return 20.0
        }
    }
```

any idea on how I could achieve this? 
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I also set the following when defining my searchController

```
 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
 searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Groups", "People"]
 tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
 searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
 searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
 self.definesPresentationContext = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen UISearchController search bar delegate and if it becomes first responder - call your_tableView.reloadData() function.

Comment: Thank you. That actually works, but since the scope buttons are animated when they appear and the tableView header height is not, you can kinda see the gray space for about a second before it's filled by the scope buttons. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: sorry, its hard to say, if it still actual for you, provide screencast or short video.